# Need finding the right tactic over Int.lt

Tags: coq, compcert

I have the following Lemma but couldn't prove it:

```
Lemma my_comp2: forall i t:Z,
t<i -> Int.ltu (Int.repr i) (Int.repr t) = false.
Proof.
....
```

I found the tactic for equality  [(link)](http://compcert.inria.fr/doc/html/Integers.html)  but can't find the one for lt/ltu or gt/gtu:

```
Theorem eq_false: forall x y, x <> y -> eq x y = false.
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: Could you add the minimal `Require` you have so we can run your lemma ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This lemma cannot be proved because it is false. And here is a counterexample for the case where `wordsize = 8` bits (I'll leave the generalization to you).

Let's take `i = 256` and `t = 255`. Clearly, the premise of the lemma is true (`t < i`). Then, `(Int.repr i) = 0` because of the integer wrap around. `(Int.repr t) = 255`, since there is no overflow in this case, but `ltu` will return `true` for the aforementioned values, not `false` as the lemma states.

```
Definition i := 256.
Definition t := 255.

Eval compute in ltu (repr i) (repr t).  (* returns true *)
```

---

As for the theorem `eq_false`, it differs significantly from your lemma, since `x` and `y` belong to `int`, not `Z`:

```
Check eq_false
 : forall x y : int, x <> y -> eq x y = false
```

Hope this helps.